# Usage of Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to learn SQL Server and got confused about use of foreign key. I'm good with creation, altering and dropping the foreign keys., by my doubt is that when the Foreign key is useful!

1st table is 'subject', having 'subject'(primary key) and 'teacher' in it.

2nd table is 'Class', having 'Class'(primary key) and 'Floor'.

I made the 3rd table 'Details' with 'class' and 'subject'.

'details.subject' is the foreign key reference to 'subject.subject AND 'details.class' is the foreign key reference to 'class.class'. Now Im confused how can I see all the details in one excecution?

```
SELECT *
FROM Details
```

is giving only class and subject from the table 'Details'. But I want to get " details.class, class.floor, details.subject, subject.teacher " when I run a singe query. If we get the mentioned output only if we use 'JOINS', then why we should use 'Foreign Key' :o

I think you understand my doubt.. Im stuck, Please help :p

Comment: Did you check in internet ?Go through w3 schools there will be good examples

Comment: Refer this links i thing this will help you , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.htm ,http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to prevent actions that would destroy links between tables. The FOREIGN KEY constraint also prevents invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the table it points to.
Also you if you have foreign key relation ship between 2 tables. And you have enabled cascade on deletion then if parent row deleted it will automatically deletes related row in child table.

Comment: Exactly yes. You will have to reply on joins for get required data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anjum . So, you mean adding a foreign key is not for auto referencing to a particular data set. Even if I use foreign key, I should relay on 'Joins' to display the required data. The foreign key will help to avoid the loss of information by altering or deletion of the main table. is it?